# how do i inherit my abstract class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, pure-virtual

I am new to c++ and currently learning inheritance. I am not sure how to properly inherit my abstract class `MapItem`, I keep receiving these errors ..

error snippet

```
     hidden overloaded virtual function 'MapItem::tick' declared here:
          different qualifiers (const vs none)
              virtual void tick() const = 0;

         Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
              "Residential::Residential()"
```

It is also claiming that my class `Residential` is an abstract class.
The program only successfully compiles and runs when I add the `const` keyword to the `tick()` function. But quiet obviously, this is a problem because `tick()` needs to operate on some class member variables. 
I properly included all the files and my make file is targeting all the correct files, which makes this error out of my understanding.

map_item.h

```
// abstract class

class MapItem {
 ...
 virtual void tick() const = 0;
}
```

residential.h

```
#ifndef RESIDENTIAL_H
#define RESIDENTIAL_H

#include "map_item.h"

class Residential : public MapItem {

    private:
        int capacity;
        double taxRevenue;

    public:
        Residential();
        virtual ~Residential();
        void tick();
        double collectTaxes();  
};

#endif
```

residential.cpp

```
#include "residential.h"

Residential::Residential() {
    capacity = 1;
    taxRevenue = 0.0;
}

Residential::~Residential() {}

void Residential::tick() {
}

double Residential::collectTaxes() {
    taxRevenue = 0.0;
    return taxRevenue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem's simply that in `Residential` you declare and define `tick` as follows:

```
void Residential::tick()
```

...while the abstract base has...

```
virtual void tick() const = 0;
```

You should add the `const` to `Residential::tick`, or remove it from `Mapitem::tick`, so they're consistent.  You say...

> The program only successfully compiles and runs when I add the const keyword to the tick() function. This is a problem because tick() needs to operate on some class member variables.

...so it sounds like removing it is what you want to do.

---

It's also a good idea to add `override` to `Residential::tick()` so the compiler's obliged to verify that it matches `MapItem::tick()`:

```
void Residential::tick() [const] override
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a HW assignment and the assignment requires MapItem::tick() to be a pure vritual function which to my understanding requires the "const = 0;" in the class definition ... which is something im not exactly sure about ALSO ... Residential::tick() cannot be a constant function because it needs to operate on some class members. again im new to c++ so im not sure what to do here

Comment: maybe my understanding of a pure virtual function is incorrect. but as of now it requires the const  = 0; part

Comment: @infetsor: "pure virtual" just means it is `virtual` and has the `= 0`... it does not need to be `const`.  Basically, pure virtual just marks the function as needing to be overridden in a derived class before a class instance can be instantiated.  There's no reason that should have any relationship to whether the function's `const`, and it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Declaring a member method results in a function declaration that takes an implicit this pointer as a first parameter.

So a method `void Residential::tick()` (without the const at the end) results in a function like `void Residential::tick(Residential* this)`.

Now adding the const at the end `void Residential::tick() const` can then be understood as a declaration with a const this pointer:

```
void Residential::tick(const Residential* this)
```

so, when you declare `void Residential::tick() const` in base class and then declare `void Residential::tick()` in derived class, the function signatures donot match and compiler throws an error.

So, decide which signature you need(const qualified/non const) and make sure both the signatures match.